# How to assign Batch ID based on same column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have questions regarding on assign Batch ID to rows with same columns.

I.E.

I have table below:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
a  b  c  d  e 
a  a  b  c  d
a  b  b  d  e
a  b  c  d  e
a  a  b  c  d
b  b  c  d  e
```

And I want to add Batch ID based on colunms c2 to c4.

result in:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 BID
a  b  c  d  e  1
a  a  b  c  d  2
a  b  b  d  e  3
a  b  c  d  e  1
a  a  b  c  d  2
b  b  c  d  e  1
```

Please help, and please also use column name instead column number in the code (`c2`, `c3`, `c4` instead of `df[,2:4]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea via base R,

```
match(do.call(paste, df[c('c2', 'c3', 'c4')]), unique(do.call(paste, df[c('c2', 'c3', 'c4')])))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1
```